# AngularJS date comparison in ng-if

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have 2 dates:

```
$scope.date = new Date();
```

And date from array which looks like this:

```
visits[1].when = "2015-09-05T10:00:00+0300";
```

Using AngularJS ng-if method I want to compare if this date is today:

```
ng-if="date | date:'d M' == visit.when | date:'d M'"
```

However, it does not work. Any issues?

Comment: You may need to use parens: `(date | date:'d M') == (visit.when | date:'d M')`.

Comment: Thank you, it works!!! Please write your comment as answer, I will accept it. :)

Comment: Oops, too late, but glad it works now :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

not any issue only you forget to take brackets...
see [this plunker....](http://plnkr.co/edit/1SaTOm2QSF7I3KgIHNeV?p=preview)

```
 <p ng-if="(date | date:'d M') == (when | date:'d M')">hi date</p>
```